# Hawq init failed -- "postgres" is needed by initdb

Tags: postgresql, hawq

After I build incubator-hawq on Centos7.1, I tried to init it. But the error below occurs:

```
20160516:18:10:43:002036 hawqinit.sh:host-172-16-0-105:hawqadmin-[INFO]:-Loading hawq_toolkit...
ALTER ROLE
20160516:18:10:44:001766 hawq_init:host-172-16-0-105:hawqadmin-[INFO]:-20160516:18:10:43:002036 hawqinit.sh:host-172-16-0-105:hawqadmin-[INFO]:-Loading hawq_toolkit...
20160516:18:10:44:001766 hawq_init:host-172-16-0-105:hawqadmin-[INFO]:-Master init successfully
20160516:18:10:44:001766 hawq_init:host-172-16-0-105:hawqadmin-[INFO]:-Init segments in list: ['hawq-master']
20160516:18:10:44:001766 hawq_init:host-172-16-0-105:hawqadmin-[DEBUG]:-Start to init segment on node 'hawq-master'
20160516:18:10:44:001766 hawq_init:host-172-16-0-105:hawqadmin-[INFO]:-Total segment number is: 1
fgets failure: Success
The program "postgres" is needed by initdb but was either not found in the same directory as "/usr/hawq/bin/initdb" or failed unexpectedly.
Check your installation; "postgres -V" may have more information.
20160516:18:10:45:002318 hawqinit.sh:host-172-16-0-105:hawqadmin-[ERROR]:-Postgres initdb failed
20160516:18:10:45:002318 hawqinit.sh:host-172-16-0-105:hawqadmin-[ERROR]:-Segment init failed on host-172-16-0-105
20160516:18:10:45:001766 hawq_init:host-172-16-0-105:hawqadmin-[INFO]:-20160516:18:10:45:002318 hawqinit.sh:host-172-16-0-105:hawqadmin-[ERROR]:-Postgres initdb failed
20160516:18:10:45:002318 hawqinit.sh:host-172-16-0-105:hawqadmin-[ERROR]:-Segment init failed on host-172-16-0-105
20160516:18:10:45:001766 hawq_init:host-172-16-0-105:hawqadmin-[ERROR]:-HAWQ init failed on hawq-master
20160516:18:10:46:001766 hawq_init:host-172-16-0-105:hawqadmin-[INFO]:-0 of 1 segments init successfully
20160516:18:10:46:001766 hawq_init:host-172-16-0-105:hawqadmin-[ERROR]:-Segments init failed, exit
```

When I type the command, the below shows:

```
[hawqadmin@host-172-16-0-105 hawqAdminLogs]$ postgres -V
postgres (HAWQ) 8.2.15
```

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If "postgres -V" works, that means the postgres binary is good.

Before you do "hawq init cluster", please make sure:

1) $GPHOME in greenplum_path.sh is correctly set to the directory of hawq binary, i.e, /usr/hawq in your case

2) source $GPHOME/greenplum_path.sh

3) check if initdb and postgres binary is in $GPHOME/bin

Answer (score 1):

From the error you pasted above, 2 possible causes:

(1) The binary `postgres` called is not `/usr/hawq/bin/postgres`, You can use `which postgres` to check the path.

(2) The dependent lib for postgres may be wrong. You can use `ldd` for linux or `otool` for mac to print all dependent lib paths, and check them.

Moreover, if any error when init hawq, please check log in `~/hawqAdminLogs/`, you may find out the specific error message.

Hope it will help you to find out the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I faced same error while initializing cluster.
`Postgres -V` showed correct version, `which postgres` showed `/usr/local/hawq/bin/postgres`, also the path was already set, still faced above error.
Finally resolved by setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/usr/local/hawq/lib/` and sourced it via `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have installed hawq binaries in different directory . Please check the following

1.Make sure you have all the right PATH set

2. Check hawq initdb binaries are there in /usr/hawq/bin/ directory

Comment: @partheesh_nair First, what's the right PATH? What should be included in PATH? Second, hawq initdb binaries are in /usr/hawq/bin/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure you have successed compile hawq and install them
2. check postgres is in the same dir with initdb
3. if there are more than 1 postgres in your pc, make sure the path of postgres(the same dir with initdb) is in your PATH.